# Wagtail Form in jQuery SlideOut Box

Tags: jquery, forms, wagtail

I am creating a website using the Wagtail CMS. My client would like a form in a jQuery SlideOut Box that appears when the user clicks a button. I am not sure the best way to go about this; I have a separate Contact Form on the Contact Page as well, and the `form_page.html` template is in the `/contact` folder. Where would I define my form for the jQuery box that is to appear on every page of the site? The code for that currently lives in the `footer.html` template file inside `/site_name/templates/includes`.

Is there any way to do this in Wagtail, or should I look into doing it with a separate Django form?

EDIT: It looks like I could possibly use a Snippet. Is this the way to go?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that a snippet will help here, because the `wagtailforms` module is designed around the idea of the form existing as a page somewhere in the page tree, at a specific URL. Even if the form itself doesn't live on any one page in particular, there has to be a well-defined URL for the form to post to - and snippets don't have URLs.

If you don't need the ability to define form fields within the Wagtail admin, a plain Django form (posting to a plain Django view) is the simplest route. To make that form object available on every page, I'd suggest defining a custom [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) - in myapp/templatetags/myapp_tags.py, have the following:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/tags/contact_form.html')
def contact_form():
    form = ContactForm()
    return {'form': form}
```

Then, within your template, `{% load myapp_tags %}` and `{% contact_form %}`.

If you do want the form to be configurable in the Wagtail admin, you could use a combination of the above approach and the `wagtailforms` module, taking advantage of the `get_form` method provided by form page models. First, set up a form page using `wagtailforms` somewhere on your site - it may or may not be an actual page that users are expected to visit (but it does need to be published and exist at a URL *somewhere*). Then, the inclusion tag code becomes:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/tags/contact_form.html')
def contact_form():
    form_page = ContactFormPage.objects.get(slug='contact-us')
    form = form_page.get_form()
    return {'form_page': form_page, 'form': form}
```

(Within contact_form.html, you would use `{% pageurl form_page %}` as the form's `action` attribute so that it posts to the form page you've set up.)

Comment: This worked, but my form is not loading for some reason. The rest of the template works, but no form in the middle. I'll post a separate question for that. Thanks for your help.